# Please reopen this question on policymaking in Japan

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

[How are policies made in Japan?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/47720/how-are-policies-made-in-japan)

This question was closed as "too broad".  Some users (including me) tried to edit the question out, but there was no avail.  I just noticed the OP had re-edited the question to get it reopened overnight, and I thought it was a good edit, and voted to reopen.  This question now has attracted two more reopen votes (1 + 2 = total **3** reopen votes) so far, but I see that some reviewers are trying to keep the question closed for no reason, and the question is not reopened yet.

---

**Can we please reopen this question?**

Comment: I see the question was narrowed down from "East Asian countries" to Japan, but it still is incredibly broad in my opinion. I doubt it can be answered definitively in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Also, please do not use `@replies` to summon moderators. That's what flags are for. And `@replies` only work for people who are already part of the conversation. For details see: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/162704) & [Flagging a post for moderator review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24560/162704)

Comment: Frankly I'm not sure we'd want to encourage low-effort one-liners like that question. And it's actually not the first such question from the same poster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I mentioned in [a comment under the question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/47720/how-are-policies-made-in-japan#comment188687_47720), I think it's still too broad even when narrowed down to a single country:

> @Matcha_boy98 it's still pretty broad. How a country makes policy is quite complex, too much for an answer here. Consider for example this [Wikipedia article on the Government of Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_of_Japan). I suggest reading such articles first and then asking questions about specific paragraphs that are unclear or questions that are not covered by the Wikipedia article. That way, you can often quote a paragraph and it provides a good introduction into the subject.

Consider that you'd be asked the question in real life, how would you answer? I would go to that Wikipedia page and list a few pointers from there. Alternatively, I'd just point them to Wikipedia page or ask a more specific question.

If we would answer here we'd basically be replicating Wikipedia. Looking at the Wikipedia page, it's rather extensive. So we'd either be giving a short summary, in which case you'd be better of reading the Wikipedia article, or you'd have a very large answer that will need a lot of updating which probably won't happen. In that case, you'd also be better of by going to Wikipedia.

In conclusion, it's really not a good fit for this site, but the author probably had something more specific in mind meaning they could easily edit the question to be more specific. If you have a more specific question, you can ask it as a new question. Reopening this question while it's too broad won't do anyone any good.